# Reverse for 'remove' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, jinja2

I want the remove obj function to be triggered when the user click on it but its throwing error:

> Reverse for 'remove' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['remove\/\(\?P(?P[^/]+)\\d\+\)\/\$$']

I want to display a list ob objects and as soon as a user clicks on the object it gets deleted

**patients.html**

```
<body>

{% include 'pages/nav.html' %}


<div class="container">

    <p>patients
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role ="button" href="/patientadd">Add Patients</a> 
</p>
<div class="list-group">
    <br>
    <br>
{% for i in names %}

<a href="{% url 'remove' pk=i.pk %}" class="list-group-item">{{i}}</a>

{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**views.py**
*minified*

```
def removeObj(request, pk):
    object = get_object_or_404(request,pk)
    object.delete()
```

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    numvisit = models.IntegerField()
    detail = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/',register,name="register"),
    path('patients/',patients,name="patients"),
    path('patientadd/',patientAdd,name="patientadd"),
    path('login/',login,name="login"),
    path(r"remove/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",removeObj,name="remove"),
    path('register/logout/',logout,name="logout"),
    path('',home),
]
```

I have tried searching but cannot find solution.

Comment: `path` doesn't take a regex (that's what `re_path` does)... it's meant for things like: `'/remove/<int:pk>'` syntax... also your `get_object_or_404` looks wrong as you don't provide it with a model class to attempt a lookup on...

Comment: `i.pk` doesn't appear to be returning anything

Comment: Please show the view `patients` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here is in your urls.py

replace

```
path(r"remove/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",removeObj,name="remove"), #this is old version of django
```

to

```
path('remove/<int:pk>/',removeObj,name='remove'),
```

## Edited

replace

```
object = get_object_or_404(request,pk)
```

to

```
object = get_object_or_404(request,pk=pk)
```

Comment: its giving error `TypeError at /remove/30/
'int' object is not iterable` I am using this removeobj function                                      ```def removeObj(request,pk):
    object = get_object_or_404(Patient,pk)
    object.delete()
    return render(request,"pages/patients.html")```